# Spring MimeMessageHelper add background image to div

Tags: java, html, background, mime

I am trying to use MimeMessageHelper to add a background image to a div in my email. The image is converted in byte array in backend and i am trying to add it by

MimeMessageHelper.addInline

I have tried adding it by this code :

```
<div id="triangles" style="height: 160px; background-image:url( data:image/png;base64, cid:trianglesBig.png); text-align:center; font-size: 180%;">
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help please ?